# Angular - add class if there are scroll bars

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/r6Lff67n/

There is no Angular here but just an example of the structure.

I have an outer div with a max-height inside of which there is content that could scroll if the content is bigger than the surrounding div.

My question is is there a simple way in Angular to add a class if the scroll bars are used so I can style it different if it will scroll

```
    <div class="scroll-outer">
      <div class="scroll-inner">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding whether a DOM object has scrollbar or not can be easily done by comparing [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) with [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) of an element.

So, I pulled up a `directive` that can compare these heights and add a class to the element with which it is bound to. Something like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive("testDirective", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (elem[0].clientHeight < elem[0].scrollHeight) {
        // scrollbar available
        // adding a custom class with sample CSS
        elem[0].classList += " mytest"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Also, custom `class` name(s) can be externalized using `directive`'s `attrs`.

Here's the working runnable code snippet and [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u66rpzo/2/).

Notice that one of the two lists of blocks has `mytest` class's CSS (border) based on whether it has scrollbar or not. You can add your custom CSS there (in `mytest` class)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive("testDirective", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (elem[0].clientHeight < elem[0].scrollHeight) {
        // scrollbar available
        // adding a custom class with sample CSS
        elem[0].classList += " mytest"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.block {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.scroll-outer {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block
}

.mytest {
  border: 3px solid black /* change this as you wish */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="scroll-outer" test-directive>
    <div class="scroll-inner">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="scroll-outer" test-directive>
    <div class="scroll-inner">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```